# Changing boot drive on Mac OS

Tags: mac, ssd, osx-mountain-lion, reinstall

I'm in the process of adding an SSD into my Mac Mini alongside the already fitted HDD (which currently has the OS).
Can I keep the HDD connected to the system while installing the new OS on the SSD?

The reason I asked is because this same task on Windows can sometimes install the boot data into the original drive (HDD in this case) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Mac os X works like you expect, unlike windows :)
The HDD will have no alterations whatsoever when you install a system on the SSD, just make sure note to erase it with diskutility

Comment: From what I've read OS X created a recovery partition also, will this be created on the SSD if one already exists on the HDD?